# How do I use chrome in WSL to connect to localhost:39000

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This might sound silly, but I just want to know if this is possible.

I am using this program called cryosparc. To access the user interface I will have to first do `ssh -f -N -L localhost:39000:localhost:39000 myusername@myhostname`, the I copy `localhost:39000` (`https://localhost:39000` does not get me into the user interface) into Chrome and it will be directed to the user interface of this program.

I want to make this process automated, and I thought I can use `/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe localhost:39000` . But it didn't do anything; it just opens a new chrome windows. I have tried `/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe otherURL`, and they all worked. So I thought I should try using `https://localhost:39000`, and it seemed to not be able to establish the connection. So I am wondering if this is a possible thing to do.

Comment: WSL has no graphics capability, WSL2 does.

Comment: You need the full prefix, and there's probably no TLS : `chrome.exe http://localhost:39000`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin WSL1 can launch _Windows_ programs, graphically or in the terminal (but no graphical Linux programs by default). In fact `PATH` also contains Windows paths.

Comment: @dan - my bad, I thought the OP was talking about opening Linux native chrome (chromium) from within WSL and running it as an X program. I understand now.

Comment: Take a look  https://discuss.cryosparc.com/t/windows-ssh-tunneling/4167/4

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable insights. And thank you @ufopilot, this discussion solved my problem.